# Firebase multiple sessions running?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I made a simple online web-app to practice what I've learnt this half of the year at univ and turned out interesting (to me & my friends). The app is very simple, you register (used firebase authentication), then log-in and you create simple notes for stuff you have need to remember. It works almost at 100% but I have to fix some UI stuff and this issue...

When I sign in to the app, and then other person enters the link from their device, they somehow are inside my account and that shouldn't happen. How can I approach this to be fixed? Add a timer for inactivity to call the signOut() method? Or how is a way to make my app recognise each device for having multiple sessions runing at the same time?

The code is vanilla js, firebase authentication and firebase firestore.

Comment: You issue is not clear. What link are you referring to? Are you trying to login multiple users on same device? Maybe share your code and then try to explain it.

Comment: As Dharmaraj said, need some more details, it depends how you save your session, if its on localstorage or cookie or the default firebase behaviour, it shouldnt affect other devices. If you try on the same device on the same browser its probably where you find your issue

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The issue is, lets say I enter here (stackoverflow.com) and I log into my account, then you (or anyone) from your laptop or phone also enter here (stackoverflow.com) and you are automatically logged into my account, as if you had logged to my account from your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question at face value isn't technically possible unless you are also storing the user auth state within your app for other users to facilitate.
Instead, I will answer if this is based on the same device:

Firebase's refresh token does not expire, allowing a user to return to the site or web app without having to re-authorize. To bypass this, you can configure Authentication based on the session or local instance, where if the user closes the window, it will log them out.

```js
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
// or
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

*If this is not the case which you are trying to solve, further debugging is required. Possibly a link to your project would help?*

Comment: Little to no debugging has been made, I don't know yet how to handle sessions so the auth state was stored on the app itself, that was the problem. Thanks for the tip!